Get submitted button's name in Sveltekit actions
I've got a form with 2 buttons:
<form method="POST" class="pt-10">
    <div class="flex flex-row pt-10">
        <button type="submit" name="save-and-exit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{ mode == "new" ? "Save and Exit" : "Update and Exit" }</button>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-row pt-10">
        <button type="submit" name="add-tracks" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{ "-> Tracks" }</button>
    </div>
</form>

Omitting the fields in form for simplicity.
My action looks like this:
export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request, fetch }) => {

        // create API instance
        const recordAPI = new RecordAPI(fetch);

        // retrieve the data from the form
        const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());

        // validate data and create DTO
        const record = recordDTO(data);

        // if errors returned from building the DTO (validation errors) then return the object.
        if (record?.errors && !emptyObject(record.errors)) {
            return {
                "data": record.data,
                "errors": record.errors,
            };
        }

        // save the data
        const response = await recordAPI.post(record);

        if (response.status == 200) {
            throw redirect(302, '/records')
        }

        return {
            data: record,
            "errors": response.errors,
        }
}

In the action function, is there a way to know which of the 2 buttons was the one that submitted the form? I need to know this since the flow is gonna be different depending on that.
One solution I can think of is updating the form to something like this:
<form method="POST" bind:this={formElement}>

then manually append the name of the button to the form and trigger formElement.requestSubmit(), but I was wondering if there's a way to do it directly in the action, I believe it looks more 'elegant'.

By the way, would recommend the enhance action to prevent unnecessary page reloads from form submissions.

The submitting button is already being sent. The form data will contain an entry with the button's name as key.
Would recommend giving the buttons the same name and different values:
<form method="post">
    <button name="button" value="a">A</button>
    <button name="button" value="b">B</button>
</form>

Then you just look up this key and decide what to do based on the value.
const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());

if (data.button == 'a')
  // ...
else if (data.button == 'b')
  // ...

Another option is to define different actions instead:
<form method="post">
    <button formaction="?/a">A</button>
    <button formaction="?/b">B</button>
</form>

export const actions = {
    a: async () => {
        // ...
    },
    b: async () => {
        // ...
    },
}

